# Where found difference between versions of maven war plugin?

Tags: maven, plugins, version, war

I try, but didn't found any information about what difference between e.g. 2.0 and 2.2 maven war plugin. Does it possible to find?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can view release notes [here](http://jira.codehaus.org/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=11150). Unfortunately, I didn't find any way to specify 2 versions.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing is to look at the change log

http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MWAR#selectedTab=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.project%3Achangelog-panel